# UITableView not scrollable but enough height

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

I'm building a Storyboard where I have a Scroll View which contains a Table View. 
The first thing I did is to disable scrolling on the Table View, otherwise we'll get two nested scrollbars, erk !
But here is my problem, I want the Table View to have its height equals to the sum of its cells's height. ( Cells height are various, because they display comments ).

PS: For the dynamic cells height I used this :

```
self.commentsTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 90.0
self.commentsTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Shortly: I want a Table View to behave like a height variable list.

Answer (score 3):

There could be other ways also to do this, but in my case i have done this,

So what you have to do is, first let the tableView's all cells load so you can check is all tableView cell are loaded as below,

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    //Update tableView Offset
    if indexPath.row() == (tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows.last! as! NSIndexPath).row {
        //End of loading all Visible cells
        self.updateTableViewOffsetForTableView(self.tableView, withHeightConstraint: self.heightConstraintTableView)
        //If cell's are more than 10 or so that it could not fit on the tableView's visible area then you have to go for other way to check for last cell loaded 
    }
}
```

And then after this you have to get the required height for your tableView and set this height to the tableView's height constraint to increase tableView's height to visible all cell without scrolling tableView but you would need to scrollView.

```
func updateTableViewOffsetForTableView(tableView: UITableView, withHeightConstraint heightConstraintToBeUpdated: NSLayoutConstraint) {

    var heightRequiredForTable: CGFloat = tableView.contentSize.height
    //Set some random height first, it is easy for tableView to shrink its height to high to low.
    heightConstraintToBeUpdated.constant = 300
    self.view!.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.view!.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()

    //Update the height constraint with height required for tableView 
    heightRequiredForTable = tableView.contentSize.height
    heightConstraintToBeUpdated.constant = heightRequiredForTable
    self.view!.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.view!.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
}
```

That's it, if you have set your scrollView's constraints set correctly then it will definitely work as you are expecting...

**Update**

I have created a demo having dynamic cells, see the output below,

Scrollable TableView:

[image]

Scrollable ScrollView:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I doesn't work because contentSize.height returns numbers of rows * estimatedRowHeight, but my rows's height are variable. Ideas ?

Comment: No, contentSize does not return estimatedRowHeight, it returns height required for tableView to show all cells. I have created demo having dynamic height cells and it is working as expected. See the updated answer.

Comment: On iOS 13 using XCode 11, the `contentSize` isn't updated instantly without forcing a layout cycle.  
Pre iOS 13, `tableview.contentsize.height` returns the correct height. But for iOS 13 you must call `layoutIfNeeded` to get the correct `contentSize`. I'm still looking for references that could clarify if there's any layout cycle changes on UITableview but so far I can't find any.